# Custom image sizes quality

Tags: images

Images uploaded on my WordPress website are too heavily compressed.
I found out that WordPress automatically compresses images and you can change that with a filter:

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', function($arg) { return 100; });
add_filter( 'wp_editor_set_quality', function($arg) { return 100; });
```

But this doesn't fix my problem. Different image sizes are still compressed.

[image: Full size: good quality]

[image: Medium size: bad quality]

Can someone help me fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What makes you say the 2nd image is too heavily compressed? Loss of detail is unavoidable when resizing, and I don't see any JPEG artefacts.

Comment: In my opinion this is way too much loss of detail.

Comment: Why would WP go back and recompress all the original images? The filters apply to images when they upload, images already in the system won't be impacted unless you reupload them, you should look into a plugin for thumbnail regeneration

Answer (score 0):

Need both:

add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});

add_filter( 'wp_editor_set_quality', function($arg){return 100;} );

Comment: Tried this, didn't help :(